# InvalidDataException when deploying with webdeploy

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy

I created a package using Visual Studio.

I then copy it to a server and deploy that package locally (i have a C# program that does this, code is below)

I make changes and build V2 of the package, when I deploy it I get an InvalidDataException (full stack below):

Other details:

- OS Server2008 R2
- Only happens when the package is put into an installer, if i just build locally and run it it works every time.
- The zip files put down by the installer work fine the first time, so I can work around this problem by deleting the deployed files and then rerunning
- I am using WebDeploy v2 (but also had this problem with v1)

Error Stack:

```
Error: System.IO.InvalidDataException: Found invalid data while decoding.
 at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.DecodeDynamicBlockHeader()
 at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Decode()
 at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
 at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
 at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SerializationHelper.CopyStream(Stream sourceStream, Stream destStream, Byte[] buffer)
 at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FilePathProvider.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
 at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.Update(DeploymentObject source, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
 at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleUpdate(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
 at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncDirPathChildren(DeploymentObject destRoot, DeploymentObject sourceRoot)
 at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncDirPathChildren(DeploymentObject destRoot, DeploymentObject sourceRoot)
 at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
 at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
 at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
 at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
 at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable)
 at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
```

What my program is doing (extracted and condensed):

```
 _syncOptions = new DeploymentSyncOptions() {DeleteDestination = false,DoNotDelete = false};
 _sourceBaseOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions();
 _destBaseOptions = new DeploymentBaseOptions
 {
 TraceLevel = TraceLevel.Verbose,
 };
 var appDeploymentObject = DeploymentManager.CreateObject(DeploymentWellKnownProvider.Package,
 applicationPackage,
 _sourceBaseOptions);
 DeploymentRule rule = null;
 if (_syncOptions.Rules.TryGetValue("IISConfigFrom64To32", out rule))
 {
 _syncOptions.Rules.Remove("IISConfigFrom64To32");
 }
 var summary = DeploymentObject.SyncTo(destBaseOptions, _syncOptions);
```